# button to save or update sql database

Tags: asp.net, button, sql-update, save

I have a button and I want it to save data to the sql database if Dropdownlist5 has no value in it, but if Dropdownlist 5 has a value in it, I want the button to update the existing data in sql.  The problem is when Dropdownlist 5 has a value selected it just creates a new entry in the sql database and does not update the existing entry in sql.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "" ||  DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "" || TextBox1.Text == "")
        {
            Label1.Text = "Fill In All Fields";
        }
        if (DropDownList5.SelectedValue !=null)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ucpdapps2;Initial Catalog=OnCallWeb;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Update Dispatcher_Roles set Name = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "',Position = '" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "',Roles = '" + TextBox1.Text + "',Status = '" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "',DispatcherCovering = '" + DropDownList4.SelectedValue + "' where Name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", con);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Successfully Updated');", true);
            ClearAllData();
        }

        else
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ucpdapps2;Initial Catalog=OnCallWeb;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Insert into Dispatcher_Roles values ('" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "','" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "','" + DropDownList4.SelectedValue + "')", con);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Successfully Added');", true);
            ClearAllData();
            Label1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try using `DropDownList5.SelectedItem`.

Comment: So you're saying that `if (DropDownList5.SelectedValue !=null)` produces an unexpected result?  When this happens in your debugging, what value do you observe `DropDownList5.SelectedValue` to have?

Comment: .SelectedItem did not resolve the issue.  The debug shows on click that an entry is being Inserted.  What I am looking for is if Dropdownlist5 has an item selected in the dropdown list  I want the button to trigger the Update command and not the Insert command.

Comment: Use `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList5.SelectedValue)`. A SelectedValue is never null in webforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VDWWD comment resolved my issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).